# can you integrate the dirac delta over any domain?

Tags: calculus, riemann-zeta, dirac-delta

At eq 28 the following author takes it from 1 to infinity. I've never seen this before and i'm not sure his equation is correct.

http://bado-shanai.net/The%20Table%20of%20Integrals/intResiduesofDiracDelta.htm

Comment: $\int_A f(x)\,{\rm d}x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \chi_A(x)f(x)\,{\rm d}x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integral of the form
\begin{equation}
\int_1^∞\delta(x)f(x)dx
\end{equation}
is just $0$. Intuitively, the spike of the Dirac delta is not in the domain, so the integral only picks up $0$.

If you look closer at the integral you mention:
\begin{equation}
\int_1^∞x^{-4}\delta[\sin (\pi x)]\cos(\pi x)\pi dx 
\end{equation}
you will see that the argument in the delta is in fact oscillating between $-1$ and $1$. The value of the integral is just the sum of $x^{-4}\cos(\pi x)\pi$ divided by $\pi$ whenever $\sin (\pi x)=0$ that is for $x=1,2,3...$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{x=1}^∞\frac{1}{x^4}\cos(\pi x)=\sum_{x=1}^∞\frac{(-1)^x}{x^4}
\end{equation}
which is in fact different from what your source states. In fact I would have:
\begin{equation}
\int_1^∞x^{-4}\delta[\sin (\pi x)] \pi dx = \sum_{x=1}^∞\frac{1}{x^4}
\end{equation}
but the author justifies the cosine by saying it "comes from the derivative in the functional differential". Perhaps you know what it means, or somebody can correct my mistakes.

Comment: You have to be a little bit careful: if $f$ is $C^1$ and all its roots are simple then $\delta(f(x))$ is a distribution which is a sum of Dirac deltas at each root of $f$. But each of the Dirac deltas gets divided by the absolute value of the derivative of $f$ at each of the roots. You can intuitively see this by pretending that the change of variable formula makes sense with distributions; the rigorous proof is similar. In this case the absolute value of the derivative cancels out with the factor of $\pi$ in the integrand.

Comment: In other words, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(\sin(\pi x)) f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)$.

Comment: @Ian So, you agree with Andrea?

Comment: @anon Reading again, yes, I agree. I missed the "divided by $\pi$" part on my first reading. I'll leave my comment because it explains where the division by $\pi$ actually comes from.

Comment: @Ian thanks for the addition. Any guess at why the author would include that $\cos(\pi x)$ in the integrand?

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio I think it is not wrong, but is more confusing than it needs to be. Basically, you can avoid the absolute value by actually changing the orientation of the integral when you change variables near the roots where $\cos$ is negative. (This is just like when we write $\int_0^1 2-x dx = \int_2^1 -u du$.) So there are effectively two minus signs which cancel out. The rule I described takes care of this without having to worry about flipping orientation.